# Assign function to a variable and use it within procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am getting a problem with using 'Next Sequence Values' inside a procedure.

I have my 'external' function to return the Next Value of Sequence.
Inside my procedure, i want to assign the values of that sequence into a variable
and use that variable inside my cursor (since i am using a union statement in my cursor).

But it is not working.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure HR.insert_TBL_APP is

    --declare variables for insert
    v_TA_SNO VARCHAR2(10);
    v_TA_SEQNO VARCHAR2(6);
    v_TA_DESC VARCHAR2(10);

    --declare variable to store the sequence number
    var_TaSeqno varchar2(6);

    -- Validation
    v_check   VARCHAR2 (10 Byte);

    err_code varchar2(50);
    err_msg varchar2(100);

    v_table_name varchar2(50):='TBL_APP';

    error_found exception;


    cursor c1 is
    select distinct TA_SNO,
                 TA_SEQNO,
                  TA_DESC
                  from (                                                                     
    SELECT hdr.FIRST_NO TA_SNO,
        var_TaSeqno TA_SEQNO, -- using variable to assign the sequence no
        hdr.descrip TA_DESC     
    FROM
        FORMS_HDR hdr
    WHERE     
        hdr.seco_name = 'TST121'
    union
    SELECT hdr.FIRST_NO TA_SNO,
        var_TaSeqno TA_SEQNO, -- using variable to assign the sequence no
        hdr.descrip TA_DESC     
    FROM
        FORMS_HDR hdr
    WHERE     
        hdr.seco_name = 'TST122');


    begin

    if c1%isopen then

    close c1;
    end if;

    v_check:=null;

    FOR i IN c1 LOOP

    --assign variables for insert
    v_TA_SNO  := i.TA_SNO;
    v_TA_SEQNO  := i.TA_SEQNO;
    v_TA_DESC  := i.TA_DESC;

    begin

    -- calling the Function taSeqNoFunc and assign the 
    --sequence No into the variable var_TaSeqno
     var_TaSeqno := HR.taSeqNoFunc();
     select TA_SNO
      into v_check
      from TBL_APP  a
     where  TA_SNO = i.TA_SNO
      and TA_SEQNO =i.TA_SEQNO;

     exception
      when no_data_found then

      --insert into target table
      INSERT INTO TBL_APP (TA_SNO,
                           TA_SEQNO,
                           TA_DESC
                            )  
                            values  (v_TA_SNO,
                            v_TA_SEQNO,
                            v_TA_DESC
                            );

        when others then
         raise error_found;
       end ;

      end loop;


      exception when error_found then

       rollback;        
      err_code := SQLCODE;
      err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);      
      insert into TA_ERROR_LOG values (v_check,v_table_name,'An error 
      was  encountered '||err_code||':'||err_msg,sysdate);
      commit;

     raise_application_error(err_code,err_msg);

     end;
     /
```

The error finally goes into raise_application_error near the end:

"ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of 1 is out of range"

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: To the people who flagged this as off-topic: I agree that this isn't *the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem* but the question is complete and understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `raise_application_error()` procedure is an Oracle PL/SQL built-in.  It's provided so what we can associate a custom message to a user-defined exception.  User-defined exceptions must have numbers in the range -20999 to -20000.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99960).

You are getting this error because of this code in your inner EXCEPTION block:

```
    when others then
     raise error_found;
```

You are raising a user-defined exception but one you haven't associated to an error number with the EXCEPTION_INIT pragma.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/exceptioninit_pragma.htm#i33787). So, Oracle defaults to `SQLCODE = 1`, `SQLERRM = 'User-Defined Exception'`.

Clearly `1` is outside the permitted range of `raise_application_error()`.  Hence the error when you come to the outer EXCEPTION block.

The way to avoid this is to remove the ERROR_FOUND exception and rely on Oracle's default exception handling.

In the innermost block you want to re-raise any exception except NO_DATA_FOUND.  The simplest way to do that is remove the WHEN OTHERS clause.  Then, in the outer block you will have meaningful values for SQLCODE and SQLERRM which you can log.  Then just use RAISE to propagate them up the stack....

```
exception 

    when others then

       rollback;        
      err_code := SQLCODE;
      err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);      
      insert into TA_ERROR_LOG values (v_check,v_table_name,'An error 
      was  encountered '||err_code||':'||err_msg,sysdate);
      commit;

     raise;

end;
```

Not only will you not get an error from `raise_application_error()`, your log will contain a useful error number and message.

---

Incidentally, it is bad practice to use ROLLBACK and COMMIT like that in an EXCEPTION block.  A better approach is to write a logging procedure which is covered by the AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION pragma. That way the logging won't interfere with the wider transaction.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS610).

Answer (score 1):

The error number you pass to the raise_application_error procedure must be a negative integer in the range -20000..-20999.

For user-defined exceptions SQLCODE returns always +1, so you're passing +1 as 
the error number to the raise_application_error procedure and that's out of range.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. How do i resolve this? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Tray calling raise_application_error with an error code between -20000 and -20999. For example: raise_application_error(-20001,err_msg);

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the answer.  It can be further improved.
The  ***pragma exception_init*** is used to catch the error (in my case - Integrity Constraint).

I have removed the function to call 'next sequence value' since it can be called directly just before performing the insert.

@APC Thanks :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure HR.insert_TBL_APP is

--declare variables for insert
v_TA_SNO VARCHAR2(10);
v_TA_SEQNO VARCHAR2(6);
v_TA_DESC VARCHAR2(10);

-- Validation
v_check   VARCHAR2 (10 Byte);

err_code varchar2(50);
err_msg varchar2(200);

v_table_name varchar2(50):='TBL_APP';

error_found exception;
parent_not_found exception;   --  use it to catch the Integrity Constraint
pragma exception_init(parent_not_found, -2291);

cursor c1 is
select distinct TA_SNO,
                TA_SEQNO,
                TA_DESC
from (                                                                     
      SELECT hdr.FIRST_NO TA_SNO,
        -1 TA_SEQNO, -- assign a dummy value as sequence no
         hdr.descrip TA_DESC     
      FROM
         FORMS_HDR hdr
      WHERE     
         hdr.seco_name = 'TST121'
  union
      SELECT hdr.FIRST_NO TA_SNO,
         -2 TA_SEQNO, -- assign a dummy value as sequence no
         hdr.descrip TA_DESC     
      FROM
         FORMS_HDR hdr
      WHERE     
         hdr.seco_name = 'TST122');


begin

if c1%isopen then
   close c1;
end if;

v_check:=null;

FOR i IN c1 LOOP

--assign variables for insert
v_TA_SNO  := i.TA_SNO;
v_TA_SEQNO  := i.TA_SEQNO;
v_TA_DESC  := i.TA_DESC;

begin

 --var_TaSeqno := HR.taSeqNoFunc();  --the variable will not be used
 select TA_SNO
  into v_check
  from TBL_APP  a
 where  TA_SNO = i.TA_SNO
  and TA_SEQNO =i.TA_SEQNO;

 exception
  when no_data_found then

  Begin  -- added line to use exception

  --insert into target table
  INSERT INTO TBL_APP (TA_SNO,
                       TA_SEQNO,
                       TA_DESC
                        )  
                        values  (v_TA_SNO,
                       TA_SEQNO.nextval, --insert the nextval directly
                        v_TA_DESC
                        );

       --when the integrity constraint (parent key) error is thrown, insert into the TA_ERROR_LOG
         exception
            when parent_not_found then  
            rollback;        
            err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);      
            insert into TA_ERROR_LOG values (v_check,v_table_name, err_msg, sysdate);
         commit;

  end;   -- end begin for using the exception

    when others then
     raise error_found;
   end ;

  end loop;


  exception when error_found then

  rollback;        
   err_code := SQLCODE;
   err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);      
   insert into TA_ERROR_LOG values (v_check,v_table_name, err_msg, sysdate);
  commit;

 raise_application_error(err_code,err_msg);

 end;
```